# Creating deciles in Hive

Tags: hive

I am a first time user of Hive (was working on SQL and Teradata for the past 2 years). I am trying to add a column to a table containing

1. Id, 2. Score

The 3rd column would be a decile on score with values 1 to 10. In Teradata, I was using  the quantile(10,score) patch, is there any equivalent patch in Hive? Google does not give me any relevant answers, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Did you get a chance/method how to calculate this(decile) in Hive? I am still not able to get it.

Answer (score 4):

As of Hive 0.11.0 you can use NTILE. To create deciles I've used ntile(10) in the example below:

```
select
id, score,
ntile(10) over (order by score)
from your_table_name
```

See also: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Answer (score 1):

So this is kind of a hack, but can certainly be done using Hive's `percentile` UDF.

```
select
id,
score,
if(score <= perc[0], 1,
if(score <= perc[1], 2,
if(score <= perc[2], 3,
if(score <= perc[3], 4,
if(score <= perc[4], 5,
if(score <= perc[5], 6,
if(score <= perc[6], 7,
if(score <= perc[7], 8,
if(score <= perc[8], 9,
                     10))))))))) as quantile
from my_table a
join (
  select percentile(score, array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)) as perc
  from my_table
) b
```